# Exercise 4, Section 16 of Munkres Topology

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> A map $f:X\to Y$ is said to be an open map if for every open set $U$ of $X$, the set $f(U)$ is open set in $Y$. Show that $\pi_{1}:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_{2}:X\times Y\to Y$ are open maps.

I rephrase this exercise to my taste.

> If $(X,\mathcal{T}_{X})$, $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{Y})$, the set $X\times Y$ equipped with product topology, denoted by $\mathcal{T}_{p}$, then $\pi_{1}:X\times Y\to X$ and $\pi_{2}:X\times Y\to Y$ are open maps.

**My attempt:** let $U\subseteq X\times Y$ and $U\in \mathcal{T}_{p}$. We need to show $\pi_{1}(U)\in \mathcal{T}_{p}$. Since $U\in \mathcal{T}_{p}$, we have $U= \bigcup_{i \in I}(U_i\times V_i)$, where $U_i\times V_i \in \mathcal{B}, \forall i\in I$. We claim $\pi_{1}(U)=\cup_{i\in I} U_i$. Let $x\in \pi_{1}(U)=\{ u|u\times v\in U\}$. Take $y\in Y$ such that $x\times y\in U$. since $x\times y\in U, \exists j\in I$ such that $(x,y)\in U_j\times V_j$. Which means $x\in U_j\subseteq \cup_{i \in I}U_i$. So $x\in \cup_{i \in I}U_i$. Thus $\pi_{1}(U)\subseteq \cup_{i\in I} U_i$.

Conversely, let $x\in \cup_{i\in I} U_i$. Then $\exists j\in I$ such that $x\in U_j$. Take $y\in Y$ such that $y\in V_j$. So $(x,y)\in U_j\times V_j \subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I}(U_i \times V_i)= U$. So $(x,y)\in U$. Thus $x\in \pi_{1}(U)$. Hence $\pi_{1}(U)\supseteq \cup_{i\in I} U_i$. So $\pi_1(U)$ is arbitrary union of open sets in $X$. $\pi_1(U)$ is open in $X$. A similar proof show $\pi_2$ is open. **Is this proof correct?**

---

**Approach(2)**

let $U\subseteq X\times Y$ and $U\in \mathcal{T}_{p}$. $\forall (x,y)\in U, \exists R_{(x,y)}\times S_{(x,y)}\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $(x,y)\in R_{(x,y)}\times S_{(x,y)}\subseteq U$. Since $U\subseteq X\times Y$, $U=M\times N$, where $M=\pi_1 (U)$ and $N=\pi_2 (U)$. Thus $\cup_{(x,y) \in U} R_{(x,y)}= \pi_1 (U)$ and $\cup_{(x,y) \in U} S_{(x,y)}= \pi_2 (U)$. Our desired result. **Is this proof correct?**

Comment: One of the things I’m worried about, can any subset of $\Bbb{R}^2$ be represented as cartesian product of subsets of $\Bbb{R}$?

Comment: No, of course not. What about a circle in $\Bbb R^2$? But any **open** set in $\Bbb R^2$ is a **union** (often infinite) of open squares (products of intervals in $\Bbb R$).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma okay. What do you think of my first solution, is it “precise”? If not, where(at which step) I need to be more precise.

Comment: Approach 1 is fine, the last bit is unnecessary as by standard set theory we know unions and images commute so $\pi_1[\bigcup_i (U_i \times V_i)]= \bigcup_i \pi_1[U_i \times V_i]= \bigcup_i U_i$. The other approach is wrong.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for verifying my approach/attempt.